MapStruct NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE resets empty booleans to false?
Using the documentation for MapStruct , I see that the option for ignoring null values when updating from a source to a target is available using nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE. This works well for updating everything except my boolean values. If I do not supply a specific boolean value, it assumes as false and updates my target as such.
I have not found much else in the documentation, perhaps I'm looking over it - but I would like to avoid having to do the null checks myself at all costs so that I can have simple patch/update functionality. My hunch is that I'm looking over something or possibly lombok is the problem.
@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, nullValueCheckStrategy= NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface  StoreMapper {
    StoreMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StoreMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target="id", source="id", ignore=true)
    void updateStoreFromUpdateStoreDto(UpdateStoreDto source, @MappingTarget Store store);
}

POM
<org.mapstruct.version>1.6.3</org.mapstruct.version>
<lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>

<path>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
</path>
<path>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
</path>
<path>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</path>


Of course as soon as I post I find my own answer. I thought a Boolean object was the implied conversion to check for a null. Switching from boolean to Boolean as the variable type in my UpdateStoreDto fixed the issue.
